# XSLT - XML data extraction

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to use data from XML:

```
<SOURCES>
<LINK type="1">https://example.com</LINK>
<LINK type="2">http://example-two.com</LINK> 
</SOURCES>
```

and use it in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="type@1"/>
<a href="{type}">text</a>
```

so I can get:

```
<a href="http://example-two.com">text</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://example.com">text</a>
```

Comment: Right, and how's that working out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the context of LINK, then

```
<a href="{.}">text</a>
```

will produce:

```
<a href="https://example.com">text</a>
```

and:

```
 <a href="http://example-two.com">text</a>
```

I don't see where the `type` attribute figures in this; in any case, you need to use `@type` to get it.

---

> but how to CHOOSE witch link to use (type=1 or type=2) ?

It depends again on where exactly you are (XSLT is very context-dependent). For example, from the context of SOURCES, you can select all LINKs of type 1 as:

```
LINK[@type='1']
```

Comment: but how to CHOOSE witch link to use (type=1 or type=2) ?

Comment: @kwachu I have edited my answer. If this doesn't answer your question, edit it and add a **complete** example of your XSLT **and** the expected result.